# Xamarin iOS audio and video still playing in backgroud?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I use ISimpleAudioPlayer and Libvlc to play audio and video in Xamarin form project. But for iOS te audio and the video still playing even when the app is minimize or screen is locked. I manage to stop it in the android part by using :

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            if (_audioPlayer != null)
            {
                if (_audioPlayer.IsPlaying)
                {
                    _audioPlayer.Stop();
                }
            }
        }
```

// for video

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            myvideo.MediaPlayer.Stop();

            base.OnDisappearing();
            MessagingCenter.Send(this, "SetLandscapeModeOff");
            MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<HomeVideoPage>(this, "SetLandscapeModeOff");
            
        }
```

my AppDelegate.cs is :

```
namespace AppTemplateDS.iOS
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            LibVLCSharpFormsRenderer.Init();

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }

    }
}
```

Note : The background mode capability is deactivated in iOS Xamarin project.

please help

Comment: Google `xamarin iOS app lifecycle`. Find the method that is run whenever app goes into background. Put code there.